# Access 2010 concatenate first 3

Tags: ms-access, concatenation

I have 2 different queries and was wondering if I am able to combine them.

I have 1 query that returns the top 3 results, I have a different query that concatenates all results. What I want to do is concatenate the top 3 results is this at all possible?

here is the top 3

```
SELECT [20161107_emma].CCAT, [20161107_emma].Vertrag, [20161107_emma].CREATED_DATE, [20161107_emma].CASETXT
FROM GCRMaster INNER JOIN 20161107_emma ON GCRMaster.CONTRACT_NUMBER = [20161107_emma].VERTRAG
WHERE ((([20161107_emma].Vertrag) In (SELECT TOP 3 vertrag
    FROM [20161107_emma] as Temp
    WHERE Temp.vertrag = [20161107_emma].vertrag
    ORDER By Vertrag DESC)));
```

and here is the concatenate

```
SELECT [20161031_EMMA].vertrag, ConcatRelated("CCAT", "20161031_emma", "vertrag = " &[vertrag]) AS expr2
FROM GCRMaster, 20161031_EMMA
WHERE ((([20161031_EMMA].vertrag)=[gcrmaster].[contract_number]));
```

Comment: You could possibly use a `UNION`, but the two queries would need to have the same number of columns, with each pair of columns having the same type.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: Please show the top 3 records output from each of the two queries.  Include this in your question, _not_ as a comment.

Comment: Use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to post sample data @Pferd676

Comment: @Andre I think that that would cut and paste very badly to MS Access :) Got anything with tabs?

Comment: Heh :) My main goal is to get readable data, but you can copy&paste the formatted text to the **Output** box on that page, and use **Parse** to get the tabbed format back. @Fionnuala

Comment: What is the error? Undesired result? Also, you should cite that you are using Allen Browne's  user-defined VBA function: [`ConcatRelated()`](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) unless the name is a coincidence and to help us reproduce.